# Multiple NavigationLinks leading to UIViewControllerRepresentable destination ends up with blank screen

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I have found a minimal SwiftUI app that exhibits a bug:

```swift
class HelloWorldVC: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Hello, World"
        view.addSubview(label)

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

struct ViewControllerContainer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let vc: UIViewController

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController { vc }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {}
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            // Works:
            //NavigationLink("View UIKit VC", destination: ViewControllerContainer(vc: HelloWorldVC()))

            // Only loads the UIKit view once. It's blank on subsequent tries.
            NavigationLink(
                "Detail Screen",
                destination: NavigationLink(
                    "View UIKit VC",
                    destination: ViewControllerContainer(vc: HelloWorldVC())
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

#### Steps to reproduce:

- Tap "Detail Screen"
- Tap "View UIKit VC". You will see the "Hello, World" UIViewController.
- Tap Back
- Tap "View UIKit VC"

**Expected**:

- You should see the "Hello, World" UIViewController again

**Actual**:

- You will see a blank view. This will happen as many times as you try.

[image: Blank screen seen from 2nd try on]

Note: In the commented out code, it works properly if you only have one layer deep of NavigationLink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not working with `UIViewControllerRepresentable` correctly. You need to create a new view controller inside `makeUIViewController`, reusing it breaks the view controller lifecycle in your case.

The `UIViewControllerRepresentable` properties can be passed to the view controller when you create or update it, as follows:

```
struct ViewControllerContainer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let props: Int

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController { 
        HelloWorldVC(props: props) 
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.props = props
    }
}
```

Comment: You are totally right. I feel dumb for not realizing this earlier and spending all the time filing the bug. Thank you!